# Resolving threefold quotient singularities without the quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a threefold $X$ with an action by a finite group $G$, everything over $\mathbb{C}$.

There are some fairly nice singularities that can occur in $X/G$. For example, suppose we have a transversal $A_1$ singularity, where it is known that blowing up the quotient gives a single fixed $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundle resolving the singularity. Moreover, this resolution is crepant.

Instead of blowing up $X/G$, one can instead look at this fixed curve on $X$ in local coordinates, say $\mathbb{C}^3$ where the $x$-axis is the transversal $A_1$ singularity, and the action is (locally) given by $(0,-1,-1)$. One can blowup this $\mathbb{C}^3$, note that the exceptional divisor is fixed by the induced action and so there is now a fixed divisor. Hence, the quotient of this blowup by $G$ is smooth.

Similarly we can do this for a transversal $A_2$, $A_3$, etc... as well as an isolated fixed point with (local) action given by $(\zeta_3,\zeta_3,\zeta_3)$ where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive third root of unity. This corresponds to a cone over a triple Veronese surface.

When $X/G$ admits a crepant resolution, for example when $G\subset \operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ by Bridgeland-King-Ried, is it always possible to blowup smooth local charts to get fixed divisors, so that after sufficiently many blowups the quotient is smooth, giving a crepant resolution? I am interested in more complicated actions, where the singular quotient is not such an easy thing to work with, whereas blowing up smooth $\mathbb{C}^3$ (or eventually $\mathbb{C}^n$) is quite doable! However, I have been trying and cannot seem to always get this to work.

For a small example, let $G = \langle \zeta_6\times \zeta_3\times \zeta_2\rangle$ act on $\mathbb{C}^3$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. The $y$-axis is a transversal $A_1$ singularity, while the $z$-axis is a transversal $A_2$ singularity, and these can be blown up to fixed divisors, but the point of intersection at the origin is fixed by the whole group, and every approach I take to blowing up the smooth $\mathbb{C}^3$ never gives me a fixed divisor corresponding to this point.

My concern is that when dealing with the quotient $X/G$ you can do small resolutions, which do not show up on a smooth variety, and perhaps there is no way to get the same effect without taking the quotient first.

For example, if we take the example above and blowup the $y$ and $z$ axes, we get
$$ \{ (x,y,z),[u:v] \mid xv = yzu \} $$
with a smooth affine $\{(y,z,\frac{u}{v}\}$ and a nodal chart $\{(x,y,z,\frac{v}{u} | x\frac{v}{u} = yz\}$. A small resolution of the node is given by blowing up $(x,z)$, say
$$ \{ (x,y,z,\frac{v}{u}),[a:b] \mid xb = za,\ x\frac{v}{u} = yz \}. $$
This has (smooth) affine charts $\{(z,\frac{v}{u},\frac{a}{b})\}$ and $\{(x,y,\frac{b}{a})\}$. Blowing up the $z$-axis on the 2 charts it appears, and contracting the $[u:v]$ bundle afterward would correspond to a crepant resolution of the transversal $A_1$ and $A_2$ singularities. However, there are only fixed points and fixed curves under $(\zeta_6,\zeta_3,-1)$, no fixed divisors, and I cannot see anyway to (crepant) resolve them. (The same issue occurs if we first blowup the origin, and then the transversal singularities.)